# Is it possible to pass a property setter as a delegate?

Tags: vb.net

I made this function for quick and simple UI animation

```
Delegate Sub AnimateDoubleSetter(value As Double)
Sub AnimateDouble(Setter As AnimateDoubleSetter, [From] As Double, [To] As Double, DurationMs As Double)
    Dim t As New System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer With {.Interval = New TimeSpan(400000)}
    Dim StartTime = DateTime.Now
    Dim Diff = [To] - [From]

    AddHandler t.Tick, Sub()
                           Dim ms = (DateTime.Now - StartTime).TotalMilliseconds
                           Dim fraction = Math.Min(ms / DurationMs, 1)
                           If fraction = 1 Then t.Stop()
                           Setter([From] + Diff * fraction)
                       End Sub
    t.Start()
End Sub
```

And I use it like this

```
AnimateDouble(Sub(x As Double) cBackground.Opacity = x, 0, 0.3, 200)
```

It occurred to me though, that since cBackground.Opacity is a property, its already a pair of functions consisting of a getter/setter. Is it possible to extract the setter function from a property so I could pass that or maybe even the property itself?

Comment: I am guessing you want this to replace `Sub(x As Double) cBackground.Opacity = x` with something that is shorter?